# Tab content not changing while using Bootstrap tabs

Tags: jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I have an Asp.net Webforms application with bootstrap v4.3.1 using [Tabs](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/exE6D). The tabs are not displaying content when clicked. Clicking each tab doesn't change the content. I have used earlier versions of Bootstrap and they work fine, but other controls on my page do not work with earlier versions so I need to use 4.3.1 if possible.

```
<div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 ">
              <nav>
                <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-about-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-about" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-about" aria-selected="false">About</a>
                </div>
              </nav>
              <div class="tab-content py-3 px-3 px-sm-0" id="nav-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
                  Et et consectetur ipsum labore excepteur est proident excepteur ad velit occaecat qui minim occaecat veniam. Fugiat veniam incididunt anim aliqua enim pariatur veniam sunt est aute sit dolor anim. Velit non irure adipisicing aliqua ullamco irure incididunt irure non esse consectetur nostrud minim non minim occaecat. Amet duis do nisi duis veniam non est eiusmod tempor incididunt tempor dolor ipsum in qui sit. Exercitation mollit sit culpa nisi culpa non adipisicing reprehenderit do dolore. Duis reprehenderit occaecat anim ullamco ad duis occaecat ex.
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
                  Et et consectetur ipsum labore excepteur est proident excepteur ad velit occaecat qui minim occaecat veniam. Fugiat veniam incididunt anim aliqua enim pariatur veniam sunt est aute sit dolor anim. Velit non irure adipisicing aliqua ullamco irure incididunt irure non esse consectetur nostrud minim non minim occaecat. Amet duis do nisi duis veniam non est eiusmod tempor incididunt tempor dolor ipsum in qui sit. Exercitation mollit sit culpa nisi culpa non adipisicing reprehenderit do dolore. Duis reprehenderit occaecat anim ullamco ad duis occaecat ex.
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">
                  Et et consectetur ipsum labore excepteur est proident excepteur ad velit occaecat qui minim occaecat veniam. Fugiat veniam incididunt anim aliqua enim pariatur veniam sunt est aute sit dolor anim. Velit non irure adipisicing aliqua ullamco irure incididunt irure non esse consectetur nostrud minim non minim occaecat. Amet duis do nisi duis veniam non est eiusmod tempor incididunt tempor dolor ipsum in qui sit. Exercitation mollit sit culpa nisi culpa non adipisicing reprehenderit do dolore. Duis reprehenderit occaecat anim ullamco ad duis occaecat ex.
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-about" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-about-tab">
                  Et et consectetur ipsum labore excepteur est proident excepteur ad velit occaecat qui minim occaecat veniam. Fugiat veniam incididunt anim aliqua enim pariatur veniam sunt est aute sit dolor anim. Velit non irure adipisicing aliqua ullamco irure incididunt irure non esse consectetur nostrud minim non minim occaecat. Amet duis do nisi duis veniam non est eiusmod tempor incididunt tempor dolor ipsum in qui sit. Exercitation mollit sit culpa nisi culpa non adipisicing reprehenderit do dolore. Duis reprehenderit occaecat anim ullamco ad duis occaecat ex.
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you get any warnings or errors in the console when you try to switch tabs? By the way, it might sound silly but keep in mind the text is the same across all tabs. I'm not sure if you have changed it.

Comment: @NickGatzos No, I do not get any warnings. I am aware that the data is the same :) I just copied this example from the Bootsnip link although I'm using the same style. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not with the version of Bootstrap or the tabs themselves but another piece of script that was preventing the clicked tab from becoming active. Removing this script resolved the issue:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".nav-link").click(function () {
$(".nav-link").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Clicking on each tab seems to work but the data is not changing

Is it because you have the **same tab content data** for all 4 tabs??

The tab is working fine for me.

Comment: David, I have pasted your example into my application and I get the same results. I can click each tab and although the tab headers change, the data  within the tab does not change. It shows the first tab results for each tab.

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in fiddle?

Comment: David, please see the edit to my post. I found the script that was causing the issue. I still do not know why this piece of script works in earlier versions of Bootstrap but not the latest. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @Shane: why do you need to bind the click event on `.nav-link`? Changing the active inactive class is already done via the data attribute `data-toggle="tab"` by the tab plugin already.

Comment: David, the older version of bootstrap didn't bind the click event for some reason. It may have been a conflict with another script on the page but that fixed the problem for me at the time. Since removing that script the active/inactive classes are working fine and data is showing as it should. It was a very simple solution but one that took days for me to track down. Thanks for steering me in the right direction.